# convert query String to json in php

Tags: php

I send a QueryString formatted text like bellow to a php Script via Ajax:

```
title=hello&custLength=200&custWidth=300
```

And I want to convert this text to a JSON Object by this result in PHP:

```
{
    "title" : "hello",
    "custLength" : 200,
    "custWidth" : 300
}
```

How can i do that. Does anyone have a solution?

**Edit :** 
In fact i have three element in a form by **title** , **custLength** and **custWidth** names and i tried to send these elements via **serialize()** jquery method as **one parameter** to PHP script.

this code is for Send data to php:

```
    customizingOptions  =   $('#title,#custLength,#custWidth').serialize();

$.post('cardOperations',{action:'add','p_id':p_id,'quantity':quantity,'customizingOptions':customizingOptions},function(data){

if (data.success){

    goBackBtn('show');

    updateTopCard('new');           
}                   

},'json');
```

in PHP script i used **json_encode()** for convert only **customizingOptions** parameter to a json.
But the result was not what I expected and result was a simple Text like this:

```
"title=hello&custLength=200&custWidth=300"
```

Comment: Which part is it that you're stuck with? Reading the query string or writing the JSON?

Comment: echo json_encode($_GET); try this

Comment: I have added more details to question.

Comment: @ahmad : Added full details to my answer for later reference, simplifying needed code to 2 function calls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$check = "title=hello&custLength=200&custWidth=300";
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,=,&]+/", $check);
$arr=array();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($keywords);$i++)
{
$arr[$keywords[$i]] = $keywords[++$i];
}
$obj =(object)$arr;
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Try This code You Get Your Desired Result

Comment: You can use parse_str of php, why you make all that function? https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is old, but I've found the most concise and effective solution to be the following (assuming you can't just encode the `$_GET` global):

```
parse_str('title=hello&custLength=200&custWidth=300', $parsed);

echo json_encode($parsed);
```

Should work for any PHP version >= 5.2.0 (when `json_encode()` was introduced).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way how to achiev JSON object from `$_GET` string is really simple:

```
json_encode($_GET)
```

this will produce the following json output:

```
{"title":"hello","custLength":"200","custWidth":"300"}
```

Or you can use some parse function as first (for example - save all variables into array) and then you can send the parsed output into `json_encode()` function.

Without specifying detailed requirements, there are many solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but i want to encode only one parameter of a Get Request that contain a queryString formatted text. I have added more details to question. I thank you once again see