# How to convert string to json, and get all key's value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some strings, the format like this

```
name=bob&age=10&sex=male&weight=80&...
```

And I want to convert it to json format

```
{
  "name":"bob",
  "age":"10",
  "sex":"male",
  "weight":"80",
  //and more
}
```

I wrote some codes, but I don't know how to continue

```
$co="name=bob&age=10&sex=male&weight=80&...";
$toarray = explode("&", $co);
```

Does someone give some tips? Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert query String to json in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214868/convert-query-string-to-json-in-php)  (specifically the second answer, IMO that should be the accepted one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use parse_str for the same,

```
parse_str("name=bob&age=10&sex=male&weight=80", $output);
echo json_encode($output);
print_r($output); // if you need normal array.
```

> **Explanation:** It will capture all URL string as an array to output. As I see you need JSON string I used json_encode to convert array to string.

Here is [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) you can refer for details.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yc57b).

Answer (score 0):

```
$co="name=bob&age=10&sex=male&weight=80&...";
$result = [];
foreach (explode('&', $co) as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $item);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```